# How to prevent divs and buttons overlaping on each other?

Tags: html, css

I have three different elements. Two divs and 1 button. I'm trying to make them look nice, and not overlaps each other, but when the content of one div is bigger, everything is ruined. I tried to use `overflow` and `min-height` properties, but it didn't work. Any advice?

```css
.lk .popup .popup-masterclass {
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
}

.lk .popup .masterclass-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 138px;
}

.lk .popup .popup-roundtable {
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
}

.lk .popup-close-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(14, 17, 22, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .lk .popup .close-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Inside `.twig` they all are next to each other like this:

```html
<div class="popup-masterclass"></div>
<div class="popup-roundtable"></div>
<div class="popup-close-text close close-mobile">{{ t("lk.close.popup") }}</div>
```

And all of that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Agree. With you structure you have only 48px for description. You could set same height to description block and `overflow:hidden;` but I guess it's not what you expect. Try Flex layout to have responsive amount of space for text